# Checkbox detection is ticked or not opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, omr

[image]

I have been trying to detect the checkboxes. Though I was able to detect the checkboxes in images but I can't detect the checkbox is checked or not. If checkbox is checked then the checkbox is bounded by some colour and if checkbox is unchecked then the box is bounded by some other colour.

This is my code :

```py
import os
import sys
import cv2
file_path = "page1.jpg"
if os.path.isfile(file_path):

    # read the image
    img = cv2.imread(file_path, 1)
    # convert to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # obtain inverse binary image
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # find contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # select contours having a parent contour and append them to a list
    contour_list = []

    for h in hierarchy[0]:
        if h[0] > -1 and h[2] > -1:
            contour_list.append(h[2])

    print("contours found: " +str(contour_list))

    # copy original image
    img2 = img.copy()

    a = 0
    # calculate the average size of contour and use this rough size for assuming we have a checkbox
    for j, i in enumerate(contour_list):
        a = a + cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    mean_area = int(a / len(contour_list))

    boxes_found = 0
    options = 0
    answer = 0

    # draw those contours
    for cnt in contour_list:
        # if contour roughly matches our average size
        if (cnt > 0) & (cv2.contourArea(contours[cnt]) > mean_area):
            # print len(contours[cnt])
            options += 1
            answer += 1
            if len(contours[cnt]) > 210:
                # larger contour length signifies a tick
                cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours[cnt]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                print("option: "+str(options)+" ticked")
                # print str(options) + " options"
                # options = 0
            else:
                cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours[cnt]], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            boxes_found += 1


    cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    print("Boxes found: " + str(boxes_found))

else:
    print("no file")
```

Comment: please show pictures of those checkboxes.

Comment: Hi Christoph I added the image url in top of the page. Can you check it.

Comment: i've added the tag for "Optical Mark Recognition". that is what you are trying to do. *knowing* the term should help you find resources on the internet.

Comment: Hi Christoph, do you know how to extract the text in checkbox region like in that image individual is ticked how can i extract the text individual.